# url pattern formed by .get() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have JQuery part that sends ajax query to the server.

```
$.get('/article', {'word': word}, function(data) {
  $("#article" ).text(data)
}
```

This makes me this url formed:

```
localhost/article?word=word1
```

But I want to have this: `localhost/article/word1` (without "?" and "=")

How can I achieve this?..

Comment: used .htaccess and rewrite your URLS

Comment: You could use `.replace("?","").replace("=","");` to remove ONLY the `?` and `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply:

```
$.get('/article/' + word, function(data) {
  $("#article" ).text(data)
}
```

(I am assuming you already took care of the routing in your application)

Comment: yeah.. that works for me. just was not sure about the .get(), that it would accept it. My initial {'word':word} looks overcomplicated now. Kind of not obvious that it going to use "?" and "="

Comment: I don't see why it should be a problem. You need to pass a `string` as the first argument of `.get()` and you are using a string concatenation.

Comment: not a problem anymore. just was not familiar with overrided versions of .get()

Answer (score 1):

As first u need to write .httacces friendly urls
and get will looks

```
$.get('/article/word'+word, function(data) {
  $("#article" ).text(data)
}
```

Comment: that is easy. But why I need change .httaccess ? It works even without it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
$.get('/article/' + word, function(data) {
    $('#article').text(data);   
});
```

You can also just modify .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/article\?word=(.*)$ /article/$1 [L,R]
```